# Kotlin KAPT to KSP can't find bean

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, micronaut

I'm trying to migrate from KAPT to KSP, after updating Kotlin version to 1.9.21, Micronaut version to 4.2.2, and JDK to 17.

Everything works fine with KAPT, but when I switch to KSP, it builds, but at run-time, it throws an exception and terminates.

Literally the only changes are these lines:

```
plugins{
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.9.21"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.21-1.0.15"
}
and
dependencies{
    kapt(platform("com.example:client-bom:${client-version}"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
}
```

I'll comment out one plugin and try the other and switch the kapt -> ksp in the dependencies.

KAPT builds and runs fine.
KSP builds fine, but when run, spits out this:

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [com.example.client.Client] exists.

Any ideas why KSP isn't finding the bean, but KAPT is?